# Fetch content of all div with same class using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am new to HTML DOM parsing with PHP, there is one page which is having different content in its  but having same 'class', when I am trying to fetch content I am able to get content of last div, Is it possible that somehow I could get all the content of divs having same class request you to please have a look over my code:

```
<?php
    include(__DIR__."/simple_html_dom.php");
    $html = file_get_html('http://campaignstudio.in/');
    echo $x = $html->find('h2[class="section-heading"]',1)->outertext; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, you have

```
echo $x = $html->find('h2[class="section-heading"]',1)->outertext;
```

as you are calling `find()` with a second parameter of 1, this will only return the 1 element.  If instead you find all of them - you can do whatever you need with them...

```
$list = $html->find('h2[class="section-heading"]');
foreach ( $list as $item ) {
    echo $item->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The full code I've just tested is...

```
include(__DIR__."/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://campaignstudio.in/');

$list = $html->find('h2[class="section-heading"]');
foreach ( $list as $item ) {
    echo $item->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

which gives the output...

```
<h2 class="section-heading text-white">We've got what you need!</h2>
<h2 class="section-heading">At Your Service</h2>
<h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel for your valuable input, but as you can see in source code of this site there are three <h2 class="section-heading"> while adding your code returns two contents of these 3 classes of h2. Request you to help in my mentioned doubt. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just added the full code and the output of the 3 classes.

Comment: I don't know sir why at my end its not giving output as you mentioned. outputting as <h2 class="section-heading">At Your Service</h2>
<h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2> first one is missing somehow

Comment: I guess here there is no way to share screen shot else I would have shared you screen shot its still giving on two contents out of three.

Comment: Sir what I found is that last two <h2> have only class="section-heading" while the first one is having two class="section-heading text-white" does it is creating any concern, please help with your opinion sir if possible.