# Scrape Data from HTML page using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am new in Web Scraping. I have one HTML page from which I am looking to scrape data. I have managed getting data like title etc using below code

```
$name= $html->find('h1[class=page-title]', 0)->plaintext;
```

But Now I have one div like below

```
<div class="company--performance-data">

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-price-prev-close field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Previous trading day’s Close</div>
                <div content="61.58000" class="field__item">
        $61.58
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-price-current-high field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Current high for the day</div>
                <div content="64.40000" class="field__item">
        $64.40
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-price-current-low field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Current low for the day</div>
                <div content="62.78000" class="field__item">
        $62.78
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-days-volume field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Day's Volume</div>
                <div class="field__item">
        406
            </div>
          </div>

      
          <div class="field field--name-field-30-days-average-volume field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">30 days average volume</div>
                <div content="0.553734" class="field__item">
        1
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-market-cap field--type-string field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Market Cap</div>
                <div class="field__item">
        $0.00
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-52-week-high field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">52-week high</div>
                <div content="72.60" class="field__item">
        $72.60
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-52-week-low field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">52-week low</div>
                <div content="42.64" class="field__item">
        $42.64
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-last-paid-div-value field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Last paid dividend value</div>
                <div content="0.47" class="field__item">
        $0.47
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-dividend-yield field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Dividend Yield</div>
                <div content="3.03814" class="field__item">
        3.04%
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field field--name-field-stock-funds-from-operation field--type-decimal field--label-above field__items">
      <div class="field__label">Previous quarter FFO</div>
                <div content="217.76" class="field__item">
        $217.76mil
            </div>
          </div>


      </div>
```

I want get each field value like $0.47 from it. But since its have class name field, I am not getting idea how I can get value from it. Anyone here can please help me for same?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there always a `<div content="...">` containing each value? If yes, why don't you get it directly?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner as You can see some div have not that value.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447744/fetch-content-of-all-div-with-same-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
foreach($html1->find("div.field__item") as $m)
{
    $txt = trim($m->plaintext);
    $attribute_array = $m->attr;
    if(isset($attribute_array['content']))
    {
        var_dump($attribute_array['content']);
    }
    var_dump($txt);
}
```

Comment: Hi! its nice but some div have not content=. Can you please expend answer for it? Thanks!

Comment: So you want the values of content="62.78000" also? i.e., the value 62.78000?

Comment: Hi! all that div have values, however some have not content so instead we can use values. Thanks!

Comment: For this div: <div content="64.40000" class="field__item">
        $64.40
            </div> do you want to pull $64.40 or 64.40000?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: Is the issue fixed?